# How to export multiple or all JSON objects to CSV with Python?

Tags: python, json, database, export-to-csv, normalization

I have the following Python script to view JSON data in normalized format for 10 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import OperationalError
# Import our files
import pg  # Various functions to interface with the Postgres servers
from db_creds import *  # The DB server and user creds

#try:
    # Connect to an existing database
connection = pg.create_connection(sourceDB_setting[3], sourceDB_setting[5], sourceDB_setting[6], sourceDB_setting[1], sourceDB_setting[2])
#Create a cursor to perform database operations
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT application_data, id FROM ssap_applications LIMIT 10;")
results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    jrec, app_id = row
    # Process each row here
    #print(jrec)
    jrec = json.loads(jrec)
    normal_json = pd.json_normalize(jrec)
    print(normal_json)
    # save to csv
    normal_json.to_csv('App_data2.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

cursor.close()
```

I want to export those 10 records to a CSV file, so far I can only export one record with this code `normal_json.to_csv('App_data2.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')` so I wonder how should I fix my script to export 10 records or all records?

Answer (score 1):

Your ARE exporting all 10 records, but you are rewriting the file every time, so each one overwrites the previous one.  The `to_csv` method includes a `mode` parameter, exactly like `open`, which lets you specify "append" mode.

```
    normal_json.to_csv('App_data2.csv', index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

I can already predict the next question: "But if I run this several in a row, the file just keeps getting longer and longer."  There are two solutions to that.  One is to erase the file before you begin:

```
if os.path.exists('App_data2.csv'):
    os.remove('App_data2.csv')
```

The other is to open the file yourself, and pass the open file handle to pandas:

```
csvfile = open('App_data2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
...
    normal_json.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

Comment: `<scold>` you read the darned documentation, just as I did. `</scold>`  There is a "header" parameter.